# Error in meanf - unused argument

Tags: r, forecasting

Having problems with a function I wrote in R using the forecast package. This is the function:

```
    generateARIMAForecasts <- function(inputTSDecompList, inputArimaOrder, fcstHrzn, cnst, drft){

  tmpSTL <- NULL;
  fcasting <- NULL;
  tsfcastList <- NULL;
  counter <- 1;

  while(counter <= length(inputTSDecompList)){
    #select the TS decompositions
    tmpSTL <- inputTSDecompList[counter]$TimeSeriesDecomposition;
    #add the lattice plot to the list of plots
    if(cnst == TRUE & drft == TRUE){
      fcasting <- forecast(tmpSTL, h=fcstHrzn, 
                           forecastfunction=function(x,h,level, ...){
                           fit <- Arima(x, order=inputArimaOrder, include.constant = TRUE, include.drift = TRUE) 
                           return(forecast(fit,h=fcstHrzn,level=level, ...))});
    }
    fcastCoefs <- fcasting$model$coef;
    fcstValues <- fcasting;
    fcastSummary <- summary(fcasting);

    #add the forecast results to the forecast list
    tsfcastList[[counter]] <- list(FinancialInstitution=LVTSFITimeSeriesList[counter]$LVTSFITimeSeriesList$FinancialInstitution, 
                             ForecastCoefficients=fcastCoefs,
                             ForecastedSeries=fcstValues,
                             ForecastSummary=fcastSummary);
    counter <- counter+1;
  }
  return(tsfcastList); 
}
```

The function takes a list of STL decomposed series, and generates Arima forecasts for each of the individual stl decomposed time series in the input list.
I have run the forecast generation manually by hardcoding for individual elements and it works. However when I try to do it using the function I get the following error

> Error in meanf(object, h = h, level = level, fan = fan, lambda = lambda,  : 
>     unused argument (forecastfunction = function (x, h, level, ...) 
>   {
>       fit <- Arima(x, order = inputArimaOrder, include.constant = TRUE, include.drift = TRUE)
>       return(forecast(fit, h = fcstHrzn, level = level, ...))
>   })
>   In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Could someone advise please?

Answer (score 1):

Hi after a few more hours manually debugging each line in the RStudio console, I figured it out the issue was my call

```
tmpSTL <- inputTSDecompList[counter]$TimeSeriesDecomposition;
```

This returned NULL because I had created the inputTSDecompList as a 2-D list using

```
tsDecomList[[counter]] <- list(FinancialInstitution=inputTSList[counter]$LVTSFITimeSeriesList$FinancialInstitution, TimeSeriesDecomposition=tsDecom);
```

So I should have been calling

```
tmpSTL <- inputTSDecompList[[counter]]$TimeSeriesDecomposition;
```